# Count words in a .txt file using bash

Tags: bash

How does one count the amount of words in a .txt file using bash?

One word would typically contain `A-z` and `0-9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`wc -w`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wc) command can do this.

Comment: Note that wc is not in bash - it is a separate executable that can be called by any shell.